# Create scope by time range on sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model with an expiration date:

```
expireAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false
}
```

I want to create a scope to find the "enabled" records, actually is:

```
// I add it on associate method, because need to use other model:

QuestionsModel.addScope("enableds", {
    where: {
        enabled: true // The question is enabled
    },
    include: [{
        model: models.users,
        where: {
            enabled: true // The author is enabled
        }
    }]
});
```

But I don't know how to validate if is expired, I need to discard the expired records (when actual date is higher or equal with expireAt).

Some idea?